# Is there an issue with the setcookie() function in this code?

Tags: php

the DB.php function works. The only issue is the cookie is not being set. Is there anything wrong with $token being input to setcookie? (after '/' I put my .mydomain.com instead of null.)

Note: (.mydomain.com is just filler I have my actual domain there.)

The code comes from here:
https://github.com/howCodeORG/Social-Network/blob/Part5/login.php

I've tried:

- Removing the echo statement (it won't load without the echo statement).
- changing $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong)); to
  $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64, $cstrong));(cookie still not set)
- I used an example from w3schools to test and the cookie set then (therefore, it's not my browser).

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
                if (password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])) {
                        echo 'Logged in!';
                        $cstrong = True;
                        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                        $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));
                        setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', .mydomain.com, TRUE, TRUE);
                } else {
                        echo 'Incorrect Password!';
                }
        } else {
                echo 'User not registered!';
        }
}
?>
<h1>Login to your account</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username ..."><p />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password ..."><p />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you enable error_reporting? Checked for the actual HTTP response (`wget -S` etc)? Have you verified a token gets stored in your DB, or this code path is reached? // Also probably should reduce the number of database queries (don't repeat it for username and password twice.)

Comment: How do you check for the cookie?

Comment: I'm using phMyAdmin and see no errors. A token does get stored in the Database. I'm following a tutorial and don't know how to reduce the number of database queries.

Comment: This is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyC0KKF-3CM according to it, you check if the cookie has been set via your browser. It's being used to keep the user logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setcookie` **must** occur before any output from your script, as it relies on sending a header to set the cookie. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and
>   <head> tags as well as any whitespace.

In your code you have `echo 'Logged in!';` before your call to `setcookie`, which will prevent it working.

Comment: I have moved the echo statement to be after the cookie has set. the cookie still does not set.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the call, `.mydomain.com` should be in quotes (also it shouldn't have  a `.` at the start. Also if you're not using SSL, the `secure` parameter should be `false`, not `true`

Comment: I have now included the quotes and I am using SSL. Why would I not use . in front of mydomain.com?

Comment: The `.` is no longer required with modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you. do cookies need to be set outside of the if statements?

Comment: No, where you have it is the appropriate place. You wouldn't want to set the cookie unless the user successfully logged in. If it's still not working, try enabling error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if you get a `headers already sent` message, which would indicate that you still have some output occurring before the `setcookie` call.

Comment: Where would I see the headers already sent message? In phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It would appear in your output page along with the `Logged in` message

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. Is the response I got

Comment: Ok, so as I suggested, you're still getting some output from your code before you get to the `setcookie`. If you inspect the page source you should be able to see what it is and hopefully track down where it is coming from.

Comment: Ok, So I commented out the lines  $user_id and DB::query which inserts into login tokens. It set the cookie. However, now the token is not being created in the database. Should I move setcookie to be created before these statements?

Comment: If it's just the two statements immediately before the `setcookie`, then moving it before should work. It's weird that your `DB::query` statement is producing output, perhaps there is an issue with the query?

Comment: I had to move $user_id before $cstrong. It works now! Thank you so much!!! I was struggling for the past 2 days with this.